# POP 2 MPLS tags with OpenDayLight

Tags: rest, sdn, opendaylight

I am using Zodiac FX openflow switches controlled by ODL on a MPLS network and
I am trying to push 2 stacked MPLS labels on a single packet(MPLS tunnel) with this flow:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<flow 
xmlns="urn:opendaylight:flow:inventory">
<flow-name>POP Z2</flow-name>
<instructions>
    <instruction>
        <order>0</order>
        <apply-actions>
            <action>
                <pop-mpls-action>
                    <ethernet-type> 8847</ethernet-type>
                </pop-mpls-action>
                <order>0</order>
            </action>
            <action>
                <pop-mpls-action>
                    <ethernet-type>2048</ethernet-type>
                </pop-mpls-action>
                <order>1</order>
            </action>
            <action>
                <output-action>
                    <output-node-connector>2</output-node-connector>
                    <max-length>60</max-length>
                </output-action>
                <order>2</order>
            </action>

        </apply-actions>
    </instruction>
</instructions>
<id>126</id>
<strict>false</strict>
<match>

    <in-port>1</in-port>

</match>
<idle-timeout>0</idle-timeout>
<cookie>401</cookie>
<cookie_mask>255</cookie_mask>
<installHw>false</installHw>
<hard-timeout>0</hard-timeout>
<priority>200</priority>
<table_id>0</table_id>
```

But ODL don´t move the flow to the operational datastore.
I have tried the same flow but with only one push action and it remove the first MPLS tag.

Is ODL limited to push only one MPLS label? What can I do?

Comment: I'm not sure about the limitations of OpenFlow Plugin in ODL, but you could enable debugging on the Karaf console just for OpenFlow Plugin and see if there is anything useful printed. `log:set DEBUG org.opendaylight.openflowplugin`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Operational datastore is populated with what's actually programmed into the switch, it goes config--->switch--->operational. with various ODL components doing various things (OF plugin, Statsmgr, fwdrulesmgr..) it can be failing at any of theses points. you can look at karaf log (set DEBUG) to see whats going on from the controller internals prospective, tcpdump ofchan to see what the controller is trying to push and look at the switch flows/log to see what gets programmed.